# unable to show a progress bar properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

i want to show in my activity a progress bar as a response to a button click.
i read in another question that i should use async task in order to show/not show the progress bar but when i click on the button the progress bar is not shown properly (it appears for much less time then it should)
any suggestions?

the activity code:

```
public void chooseContactFromList(View view){
ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
circleActivity progressTask = (circleActivity) new   circleActivity(pBar).execute();

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
CharSequence[] cs=nameList.toArray(new CharSequence[nameList.size()]);
builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
    builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            reciverNumber = phoneList.get(item);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    progressTask.cancel(true);
}
```

the AsyncTask code:

```
public class circleActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private ProgressBar progressBar; 

public circleActivity(ProgressBar pBar) {
    progressBar=pBar;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void ... progress) {

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are doing nothing in the `doInBackground()`, the progressBar is shown for few moments only. If you really want to see it, then try doing some operation in `doInBackground()` which will take some time.

eg. Try `Thread.sleep(1000);` in doInBackground to test it.

And I suggest you to refer following links.

1. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html